# use placeholder image from drawable if the image url is null or empty

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-imageview, android-image

I'm trying to do user an image from drawable folder as placeholder if the image url not found. But I'm getting dead code error when I tried to implement it. And the available image urls loads the images from JSON.

This is my code:

```
String image_file = new String( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                + "/images/" + shop.getImage());
 String place_holder = "@drawable/placeholder";
                    if(shop.getId().equals(sales.getShop_id())){
                        if(image_file != null){
                            hm.put("shop_image", image_file );
                        }else{
                                    //here I gets dead code error
                            hm.put("shop_image", place_holder );
                        }
                    }
```

Please someone help me to solve?

Edit:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

            for(Sales sales : this.response.sales){
                HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
                if (sales.getCategories1().contains("cat_id1")){
                    hm.put("sale_id", sales.getId());
                    hm.put("sale_title", "" + sales.getShort_title());
                    hm.put("shop_name","Shop : " + sales.getShop_name());
                    for(Shop shop : this.response.shops){
                        String image_file = new String( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                + "/images/" + shop.getImage());
                        //String place_holder = new String("@drawable/placeholder");
if(shop.getId().equals(sales.getShop_id())){
                        if(new File(image_file).exists()){
                            hm.put("shop_image", image_file );
                        }else{
                            hm.put("shop_image", String.valueOf(R.drawable.placeholder) );
                        }
                    }
}
                    aList.add(hm);
                }
            }

            // Keys used in Hashmap
            String[] from = { "sale_id","shop_image","sale_title","shop_name"};

            // Ids of views in listview_layout
            int[] to = { R.id.sale_id,R.id.shop_image,R.id.sale_title,R.id.shop_name};

            // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
            // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);

            // Getting a reference to listview of main.xml layout file
            ListView myList = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listview);

            // Setting the adapter to the listView
            myList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: where is the download part? of cause else is never reached. image_file is != null, no matter what you set to shop.

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
if(image_file != null)  
//The string 'image_file' will never be null according to the lines above.
```

I think you are trying to judge if the image file exists. Try this instead:

```
if (new File(image_file).exists())
```

Comment: @Kabe i think that another problem then. Please go to google first.

Comment: And the code you provided is not enough to solve the "Showing" problem.

Comment: I edited with your code and done with google. still the image not showing

Comment: @Kabe, Maybe something is wrong in your SimpleAdapter. try to find some demos about Image showing in ListView.